command SHOW SYSTEM TABLES generate an error message
Got an error message when trying to view a list of system tables on Interbase 2020 server with SHOW SYSTEM TABLES command.
Trying to view a list of system tables on Intebase 2020 server by using Interactive SQL utility. When executing command SHOW SYSTEM TABLES got such error message:
Executing of script failed
Access violation at address 0000000000DA606C in module 'IBConsole.exe'. Read of address 0000657461657243
What I do wrong?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Just trying to get a list of system tables, as it described in Interbase 2020 Product Documentation (Language Reference Guide Update1, p 195)
"To see system tables, use this isql command:
SHOW SYSTEM TABLES;"

I using next enviroment:
Windows 11 24H2;
IBConsole - v14.0.0.729
Interbase Server Version - WI-V14.6.0.899 (as I saw in Interbase Manager)
